# Apply custom Locale settings of OS to Java

Tags: java, windows, windows-7, locale, decimal-point

I just changed my Locale settings in Windows, such that the decimal symbol is a dot instead of a comma. (I didn't change NL to US or anything (since I want NL style date formats), I just set some custom format settings.)

This change is not reflected when running my Java program.

```
    System.out.println(new Scanner("4,0 ").nextDouble());
```

outputs

```
4.0
```

instead of giving an exception, while now

```
    System.out.println(new Scanner("4.0 ").nextDouble());
```

gives the exception.

How do I let Java know that the custom Locale settings are updated?
Is it even possible for Java to know these custom settings?

Comment: As far as I can see, the reference implementation does not take such customization into account. The only solution would be implementing a new [DecimalFormatSymbolsProvider](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/spi/DecimalFormatSymbolsProvider.html) using the native Windows API to get the symbols.

Answer (score 0):

```
Locale.setDefault(Locale.ENGLISH);
```

Comment: That will cause the same issue with dates instead of numbers.